# How can I increase performance of shortest-path on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I tried to use shortest-path on AgensGraph.

But, It is quietly slower than other graph database.

How can I increase performance of shortest-path on AgensGraph?

I want to some tips or configuration parameters.

Attaching sample script follow.

```
create graph shortestpath;
create vlabel o;
create vlabel l;
create elabel e;
create property index on o ( id );
create property index on l ( id );
create property index on e ( id );
create (:o{id:1})
create (:o{id:2})
create (:o{id:3})
create (:o{id:4})
create (:o{id:5})
create (:o{id:6})
create (:o{id:7})
create (:o{id:8})
create (:o{id:9});
match (o:o) create (:l{id:o.id});
match (n:l) where n.id >= 1 and n.id <= 9
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+1)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+1})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+2)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+2})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+3)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+3})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+4)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+4})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+5)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+5})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+6)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+6})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+7)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+7})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+8)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+8})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+9)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+9});
match (n:l) where n.id >= 11 and n.id <= 99
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+1)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+1})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+2)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+2})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+3)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+3})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+4)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+4})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+5)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+5})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+6)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+6})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+7)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+7})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+8)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+8})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+9)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+9});
match (n:l) where n.id >= 111 and n.id <= 999
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+1)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+1})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+2)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+2})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+3)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+3})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+4)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+4})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+5)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+5})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+6)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+6})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+7)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+7})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+8)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+8})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+9)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+9});
match (n:l) where n.id >= 1111 and n.id <= 9999
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+1)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+1})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+2)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+2})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+3)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+3})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+4)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+4})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+5)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+5})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+6)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+6})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+7)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+7})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+8)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+8})
create (n)-[:e{id:'l:'+n.id+'->l:'+(n.id*10+9)}]->(:l{id:n.id*10+9});
\timing
match p = allshortestpaths( (l1:l)-[:e*]->(l2:l) ) where l1.id = 1 and l2.id = 11111 return l1.id as l1id, l2.id as l2id, count(p) order by l1id, l2id;
 l1id | l2id  | count 
------+-------+-------
 1    | 11111 |     1
(1 row)
Time: 133.547 ms
```

Is it possible that improve to under 10ms.

Answer (score 0):

There is an improvement on Shortest-Path on "AgensGraph Version 2.1".

Algorithm is changed to "Bidirectional BFS" from "BFS".

```
agens (AgensGraph 2.1.0, based on PostgreSQL 10.4)
Type "help" for help.

match p = allshortestpaths( (l1:l)-[:e*]->(l2:l) ) where l1.id = 1 and l2.id = 11111 return l1.id as l1id, l2.id as l2id, count(p) order by l1id, l2id;
 l1id | l2id  | count 
------+-------+-------
 1    | 11111 | 1
(1 row)

Time: 1.776 ms
```

If you use "Version 1.3" or "Version 2.0", It is better choice upgrade to "Version 2.1"